# Delphi 7, Windows NT Service, Console App

Tags: performance, delphi, delphi-7

I have a Delphi 7 32bit application.  Windows 7 64bit.

Everything runs fine.   I have recently been investigation performance issues that I've noticed.

A brief overview of the application -->

Has a command-line / console app executable, written in Delphi.  This creates a multi-threaded set of connections and does database work.
An NT Service, written in Delphi (which calls the command-line application), based on the schedules of jobs it finds.  This is done via a call to our DLL, which finds and executes a CreateProcess for the commandline application, and WaitForSingleObject for it to finish.  Effectively, this service is responsible for finding when work needs to be done, and callin the executable/console app to do it.

Here's my problem, I cannot seem to figure out.

If I run the command-line application, I get roughly a 4x faster result than if I the NT Service call it via CreateProcess.  This is the IDENTICAL code.  One is a DOS prompt issuance of the EXE, the other is an NT Service, which loads a DLL, which then calls CreateProcess for that same executable.

I am going bananas.  I cannot see any reason for this.

I can reproduce this on any system configuration thus far.

What I've noticed so far (not scientific, but certainly relevant imo).

If I monitor CPU cores with CPU time AND Kernel time, the console app has a fraction of kernel time during the life-time of its execution.  When the scheduler service runs this, the kernel time represents 50-70%% or more of whatever CPU % use I am getting.

Some actual results (everything else is effectively irrelevant I believe)
- console app, run through commandline:  26 seconds
- console app, run through service via CreateProcess:  113 seconds

What gives?

I've looked into perhaps that FastMM isnt being shared properly.   I believe it is.  I even remoed it.  Same anomalies.
I've looked into perhaps the FastCode, FastMove stuff isnt working under the service (since at startup, its trying to dynamically hook/replace core RTL functions.  removed them from the equation, same anomalies.
I've looked into removing our patched RTL (System.dcu/SysInit.dcu) files.  No joy.

All to no avail.

So, my questions (and solicitation for possible reasons), are ...

Does an NT service preclude the ability to perform automation/hook replacement features?
Does Delphi services create something that would cause this?
Is there some sort of inherent overhead -- (and it is a HUGE amount) with services?
Are there alternatives to using FastMM, FastCode, FastMove that others have used because of something of this nature?

Thanks in advance for any guidances/helpers here.

Here's the snippet of code used to launch the app from the NT Service.

```
FillChar(si, SizeOf(si), 0);
si.dwFlags := SW_HIDE;
FillChar(pi, SizeOf(pi), 0);

sCommandLine := Format('"%s" "%d"', [ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'MYAPP.EXE', AJobID]);

If CreateProcess(PChar(sFilename),
    PChar(sCommandLine),
    Nil,
    Nil,
    False,
    0,
    Nil,
    Nil,
    si,
    pi) Then Begin

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, ExitCode);
    Result := (ExitCode = 0);

End Else Begin

    AddEventLogMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));

End;
```

Comment: Do you redirect console input/output on that process you spawn from the service? What service account do you use - same as desktop user?

Comment: There is no console output.  All output of the executable is logged to the database.

Comment: The service account is LocalSystem.  I've tried using the service to run as the desktop user account that runs the console app, same results.

Comment: If you want to find out why a program is taking longer than expected, the first step is to do some profiling. Attach a profiler to your program and find out which parts are taking all the time. *Then* you can figure out how to avoid those parts or how to make them faster.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue is related specifically to the use of connections, and sharing the connection.

Once I took the approach of destroying the connection on the scheduler before launching the CreateProcess, the kernel usage was back inline with what I was seeing when running directly from the console.

Very surprising, given that the connection is not even shared with what the commandline was doing.

Future reference:  Be sure to eliminate all variables before saying the two approaches were identical.  In this, they were not.  Scheduler had a connection, the console app did not.  And that was all the difference.

Comment: Unfortunatley, this is only one part of the issue.  There is still something underlying in my code which manifests itself when run as a service as oppoosed to running via the console.